# Please, what are the ubuntu 16.04 LTS screensaver installation commands?

Tags: xscreensaver

Please, what are the ubuntu 16.04 LTS screensaver installation commands? I will be grateful for any help that could help me to properly do the screensaver installation through terminal.

Comment: Hi, there are no commands for ubuntu 16.04 in the link you recommended to me. do the same command work for all ubuntu?

Comment: Try and find out.

Comment: xScreenSaver was and still is the reference screensaver for all Linux-based OSes.

Comment: ...that means it doesn't matter whether I run 16.04 LTS or 17.04 on my machine? are there any problems associated with it after installation? Thanks)